# How to make web page not reloading on back

Tags: angular, web-applications, web, web-deployment

I am pretty new to the web development. I was able to design web pages using angular. Now I am running my angular web locally and it is connected to the server.
When I open my app in the browser it displays the data returned by the server.

The issue I am facing is, I am navigating to different pages via clicks, but when I want to come back to the just previously visited page, the page is getting reloading but this will not happen if I am not wrong.

So please suggest me ideas for this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.router.navigate(['/test'], { relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true });`

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I'm assuming you are navigating to different pages using href.

Instead you can use routerLink or router.navigate like this:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/home']"></a>
```

or

```
<button (click)="navigate()"></button>
```

In your component.ts

```
navigate(){
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Comment: <li class="sub-menu"> <a routerLink="payments" routerLinkActive="active">Payments</a></li>, in this way  I am navigating

Comment: then it should not reload the whole page. can you post related code or do a stackblitz?